Why do I get errors when I want to go to the Navigation where there is a Hashlink?
Errors
App.jsx
import React, { useRef, useEffect, Suspense, Fragment } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import RootLayout from "./pages/Root";
import FullPageScroll from "./UI/FullPageScroll";
import NestedFullPageScroll from "./UI/NestedFullPageScroll";
import HeroArea from "./components/Hero area/HeroArea";
import AboutSection from "./components/About me/AboutSection";
import PortfolioSection from "./components/Portfolio/PortfolioSection";
import ContactSection from "./components/Contact me/ContactSection";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";
import ProjectDetails from "./components/Project details/ProjectDetails";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation/Navigation";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

const App = () => {
  const overlay = useSelector(state => state.navigation.isOpen);

  return (
    <Fragment>
    
      <BrowserRouter>
      <AnimatePresence>
        {overlay && <Navigation />}
      </AnimatePresence>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
            <Route index element={
              <FullPageScroll>
                <HeroArea id="home"/>
                <AboutSection id="about"/>
                <PortfolioSection id="portfolio"/>
                <ContactSection id="contact"/>
                <Footer />
              </FullPageScroll>
            } />
            <Route path="portfolio/details" element={
              <Suspense>
                <NestedFullPageScroll>
                  <ProjectDetails />
                </NestedFullPageScroll>
              </Suspense>
            } />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Fragment>
  )
};

export default App;



Navigation.jsx
import React from "react";
import classes from "./Navigation.module.css";
import Container from "../../UI/Container";
import Overlay from "../../UI/Overlay";
import { HashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import scrollSection from "../../utils/scrollSection";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {closeMenu } from "../../store/navigation-slice";

function Navigation() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  function navigateHandler(){
    dispatch(closeMenu())
  }
  return (
    <Overlay>
      <nav className={classes.navigation}>
        <Container>
          <ul className={classes["nav-container"]}>
            <li onClick={navigateHandler}><HashLink to="/#home">Home</HashLink></li>
            <li onClick={navigateHandler}><HashLink to="/#about">About me</HashLink></li>
            <li onClick={navigateHandler}><HashLink to="/#portfolio">Portfolio</HashLink></li>
            <li onClick={navigateHandler}><HashLink to="/#contact">Contact me</HashLink></li>
          </ul>
        </Container>
      </nav>
    </Overlay>

  );
}

export default Navigation;


dependencies
"dependencies": {
        "@ap.cx/react-fullpage": "^0.3.0",
        "@formspree/react": "^2.5.1",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.5",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "framer-motion": "^11.2.12",
        "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
        "react": "^18.3.1",
        "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
        "react-icons": "^5.2.1",
        "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.24.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "react-simple-typewriter": "^5.0.1",
        "redux": "^5.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },

I get an error when I want to go to the navigation without even following the Hashlink. Everything works fine without Hashlink. I also have a sneaking suspicion that there's something wrong with the dependency versions, but I've never had a problem with that.
The navigation itself is located correctly in the code (under Routing). Please help me, because I can't fix it for quite a long time.

You can't use HashLink outside of RouterProvider

Can you give me please piece of advide? How I can fix this without breaking the logic of the code?

If you say you are rendering the nav links correctly within the routing context and still have some issue, can you try creating a running Codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live? That said, React-Router-Hash-Link hasn't really been updated to "officially" support React-Router-6, some stuff still works though. See if you can create that live demo though.
